# Checking whether the contents of a file is the word "True"

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
if FILE PATH HERE==true (
   echo Success
) else (
   echo Fail
)
pause
```

I am trying to achieve something along the lines of this. I want to take a file path, and put it in the if statement. If the contents of this file is "True" do INSERT CODE HERE. That is the simplest way I can explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm left guessing you want to search a file for a particular string and if true execute a command? - `%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"String" "filepath.ext" > nul && (Echo(True) || (Echo(False)`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.